# Use OSGI bundled jar from command line

Tags: java, jar, osgi-bundle

I have the apache derby database jar files in a single OSGI bundle and working correctly in my application.

I want to use those same jar files from a command line to perform some utility commands on the database.  The client machine does not have a JDK so I can't use jar to extract the inner jars.  Is there a command line that will reference the packaged jar files inside another jar file?

java -classpath "pathToOsgi.jar/derbytools.jar;pathToOsgi.jar/other.jar" some.class

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Do you have access to one of the `zip` programs?

Comment: Nice thought but no reliable access to zip due to wide variety of end user systems